# How to apply table rules to all rows

Tags: tables, overleaf, rows

I am making a table, but it seems like the column formatting I define after `\begin{tabular}` only applies to the first row. How do I make it apply to all of the rows in the table.

```
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|p{2cm}|}
            \hline
            \hspace{.9cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont b1}& \hspace{1cm} 
             {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont I} & \hspace{.9cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont b2}& \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont Q}  \\[2mm]
            \hline
            \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont 0}  & \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont $1$}  & \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont 0}  & \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont $1$}  \\[2mm]
            \hline
            \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont 1}  & \hspace{.7cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont $-1$} & \hspace{1cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont 1}  & \hspace{.7cm} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont $-1$}\\[2mm]
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Please tell us what you're trying to achieve with all those `\hspace` directives. E.g., are you trying to center the cell contents horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me also is not clear what you're trying to accomplish. To suggestion given in nice @Mico answer (+1) I suggest:

- to use `tabularray` package:
- in document use 12p font size; it gives approx. the same font size as you write in each table cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{4}{Q[c, wd=2cm, mode=math]}},
             row{1}  = {mode=text}
             }
        b1  &   I   &   b2  &   Q   \\
        0   &   1   &   0   &   1   \\
        1   &   -1  &   1   &   -1  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you may be looking to (a) use fixed widths (of 1cm, say) for all columns and (b) center the cell contents horizontally. If this interpretation is on the mark, I suggest you get rid of all `\hspace` directives and use either a centered version of the `p` column type (in case you need automatic line braking of cell contents) or the `w` column type that's provided by the `array` package (in case automatic line breaking isn't needed). Both possibilities are explored with the following LaTeX code and associated screen shot.

Oh, and please don't stick `\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont` directives in each and every cell of the table. Instead, I suggest, you could issue a single such statement, after `\begin{table}` and before `\begin{tabular}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro and 'w' col. type
%% Centered version of 'p' col. type:
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0.5mm} % for a less cramped "look"
\fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont   % one instance is enough
\centering
    
    \caption{Using centered version of \texttt{p} column type}
    \begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{C{2cm}|} }
    \hline
    b1 & I   & b2 & Q    \\
    \hline
    0  & $1$ & 0  & $1$  \\
    \hline
    1 & $-1$ & 1  & $-1$ \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
   
    \bigskip
    \caption{Using the \texttt{w} column type}
    \begin{tabular}{ | *{4}{wc{2cm}|} }
    \hline
    b1 & I   & b2 & Q    \\
    \hline
    0  & $1$ & 0  & $1$  \\
    \hline
    1 & $-1$ & 1  & $-1$ \\
    \hline
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```